# Replace and convert string - Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, netezza

I need to select the max from a column called Sequence that is varchar. The values are listed as 1-1, 1-2, 1-3, 2-1, 2-2, 2-3, 3-1, 3-2, 3-3, etc. How can I remove the "-" (and convert to an int if necessary) to be able to use the max feature? Currently, trying to select max(Sequence) returns all the records.

```
SELECT MAX(regexp_replace(Sequence, '-', '')), Policy
FROM Transactions
WHERE Policy = '1234'
GROUP BY Policy
```

Throws the following error:

> ERROR [42S02] ERROR:  Function 'REGEXP_REPLACE(VARCHAR, UNKNOWN,
>   UNKNOWN)' does not exist  Unable to identify a function that satisfies
>   the given argument types  You may need to add explicit typecasts */

Example table:

[image: EXAMPLE TABLE]

Desired Results:

[image]

Comment: Please provide sample data *and* desired results.  It is unclear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Can you specify the version and type of postgres engine. If it is netezza then you are little bit out of luck.

Comment: Workbench: Aginity Workbench for PureData System for Analytics 4.3.1864.22949 (9/26/2014)
OS Version: Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 (64-bit)
DBMS Version: Release 7.2.0.3-P1 [Build 42685]
Driver Used: Netezza ODBC
Driver Signature: {NetezzaSQL}
NetezzaSQL ODBC Version: 7.2.0.43166
NZOLEDB OleDb Version: 6.0.8.25429

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can just use the string maximum:

```
SELECT MAX(Sequence), Policy
FROM Transactions
WHERE Policy = '1234'
GROUP BY Policy;
```

This works for the data provided.  If it doesn't work because you have values like `'1-10'`, then you can convert this to a float or decimal:

```
SELECT MAX(REPLACE(Sequence, '-', '.')::numeric), Policy
FROM Transactions
WHERE Policy = '1234'
GROUP BY Policy;
```